# Java bolt for slack mapping block json and sending it to slack

Tags: java, json, slack

I am trying to see the following message on slack:

```
{
    "blocks": [{
        "type": "actions",
        "elements": [{
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Farmhouse",
                    "emoji": true
                },
                "value": "click_me_123"
            },
            {
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Kin Khao",
                    "emoji": true
                },
                "value": "click_me_123",
                "url": "https://google.com"
            },
            {
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Ler Ros",
                    "emoji": true
                },
                "value": "click_me_123",
                "url": "https://google.com"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Now on the java side I am using gson to map this to an object and then send it using ctx.say():

```
List<LayoutBlock> blocks = answers.stream().map(ans -> 
   gson.fromJson(ans.getContent(), LayoutBlock.class)                                 
     ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now this mapping fails. If I try to use a simpler json it works:

```
{
          "type": "actions",
          "elements": [
            {
              "type": "button",
              "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Option 1",
                "emoji": true
              },
              "value": "{ \"name\": \"smalltalk.appraisal.thank_you\", \"entities\": { \"reply\": \"test\", \"option\": \"1\" } }"
            },
            {
              "type": "button",
              "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Option 2",
                "emoji": true
              },
              "value": "{ \"name\": \"smalltalk.appraisal.thank_you\", \"entities\": { \"reply\": \"test\", \"option\": \"2\" } }"
            }
          ]
        }
```

Basically what I'm seeing is that when using ctx.say(), you can either send a String or a List of Blocks:

```
  default ChatPostMessageResponse say(String text) throws IOException, SlackApiException {
        this.verifyChannelId();
        ChatPostMessageResponse response = this.client().chatPostMessage(ChatPostMessageRequest.builder().text(text).channel(this.getChannelId()).build());
        return response;
    }

    default ChatPostMessageResponse say(List<LayoutBlock> blocks) throws IOException, SlackApiException {
        this.verifyChannelId();
        ChatPostMessageResponse response = this.client().chatPostMessage(ChatPostMessageRequest.builder().blocks(blocks).channel(this.getChannelId()).build());
        return response;
    }
```

How am I supposed to convert the json shown in the slack block kit builder into a java object that can actually be sent using ctx.say()?

Comment: What exactly you  are feeding to map function?  First Json Snippet?  I

Comment: ans.getContent() contains the second json shown. Its an actionsBlock with two buttons represented in Json form

Comment: @ErikKalkoken  ?

Comment: Hey, sorry, but my Java skills are very limited. However, in other static typed languages like C# you have indeed to convert the JSON from Slack into objects.

Comment: JSON looks OK, but you have to double check what exactly you are feeding to GSON.   maybe you pass an array where object shall be passed instead.  Easy to adjust for this though.

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda Problem is that the json must mirror the structure of the objects in the java sdk in order for gson to create something out of it. I tried to look for an object extending from  LayoutBlock that could contain a list of LayoutBlock objects, but could not find it.

Comment: But you can create object yourself -  containing a list or array of LayoutBlock  and GSOIN will be happy to deserialize everything there.